# picking values from textbox in order from first to last and moving them into a separate textbox

Tags: c#, split

Hi I am new to C# and SO, I am working on a project in which the user has 1 textbox (lets call it main textbox) and then there are more (3 in this case). I want the user to be able to input anything into the `"main textbox"` and from that I need it to separate the names and send them into unique textboxes please see the image here:
[image]

I have managed to fill the first textbox but when I try filling the second and third it just sends the same content (in this case eren). This is my code:

```
var names = new HashSet<string>()
{
    maintextbox
};
var charArray = maintextbox.Text.Split(' ');

tetxbox1.Text = charArray[0];

var textbox2 = maintextbox.Text.Split(' ');
textbox2.Text = charArray[0];
```

I have divided the names by space but, I don't understand how to move on from the first one.
thanks for your time and I hope I hope I was clear enough to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you should `Split`:

```
using System.Text;

...

// we split by space (' '), we want to have at most 3 items with empty one removed
string[] items = maintextbox
  .Text
  .Split(' ', 3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Then assign

```
// if we have enough items we asign item, otherwise we assing empty string
textbox1.Text = items.Length > 0 ? items[0] : "";  
textbox2.Text = items.Length > 1 ? items[1] : "";
textbox3.Text = items.Length > 2 ? items[2] : "";
```

Comment: i do not understand this line of code and i do not just want to copy and paste i want to learn as well and it gave me an error when i tried running it .Split(' ', 3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);  the error is in the 3 i have done this to try to fix it but with no success please help

Comment: @goldx.goldx: please, check if you have `using System.Text;` among other `using` and please check *textboxes' names*: does main textbox has `maintextbox` or ` maintextBox` name? Put correct one

Comment: the issue am having is that it says : cannot convert from "int" to "char" and it underlines the number 3. i am using the correct names along side (using System.Text;) so i dont understand where the issue is

Comment: @goldx.goldx: please, provide the code which causes the compile time rrror

Comment: I have fixed the issue! and I have ran the code and it works! thanks for your help! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Why did you delete [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70229112/c-sharp-console-write-var#70229221)? It was great and spot on...