# C# Console.Write(" ", var);

Tags: c#

I'm starting to learn C# after learning Python, Css, HTML and a little bit of Js.

I have this code:

```
// Variables 

var name = "Bob";
var messages = "3";
var temperature ="34,4";

// Print First Part

Console.Write("Hello, ", name);
Console.Write("You have ", messages);
Console.Write("in your inbox. ");

//Print Part II

Console.Write("The temperature is ", temperature);
Console.Write("celsius.");
```

But for some reason the output is this:

> Hello, You have in your inbox. The temperature is celsius.

It doesn't print the var. I really know it's a very basic question lol,where's the error? Any help ?

Thanks y'all for your responses and patience, I'm sorry for my misunderstanding, I think I'm doing wrong in applying other Coding Languages Knowledge in some of the things which are new for me in C# in this case. I would take a look at all your answers, analyze them and learn from them of course. Again thanks, a lot and have a nice day. I'm gonna mark one of your answers as solutions even tough all are correct.

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: *even tough all are correct.* respectfully, I'd point out that Dmitry and Örvar's answers are *not correct for the question asked* - the question is "why doesn't this work?" and they said "you can do this instead". If the question was "why does my car make a squealing noise when I start it up?", then a response of "you can take it to the shop to get it fixed" is not an answer to the question. Yes, the mechanic will fix it and stop the squealing, but the correct answer to the question asked is "because the alternator belt needs tightening or renewing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [string interpolation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) start string with `$` prefix: `$"..."` then print the text while inserting *variables* wrapping them in braces: `{someValue}`:

```
// Print First Part

Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}. You have {messages} in your inbox.");

// Print Second Part

Console.WriteLine($"The temperature is {temperature} celsius.");
```

Answer (score 3):

Coming from the other languages you posted I can see how it would be confusing. In eg python and JS you can write something like

```
print("hi ", name, " you have ", messages, " messages);
```

And you get a nice string printed out like you expect

C# doesn't print messages like this, but unfortunately (for you), the way you have tried *is actually a legal c# syntax* but it calls a method that does not work like you think it does

That version of Write you used has a signature like this:

```
Write(string formatString, params object[] dataItems)
```

The formatString argument is a string template that requires N parameter placeholders inside the first string then N parameters supplied as arguments after the string, which will be used to fill in the placeholders. Placeholders start at zero number. You can call the method like this:

```
Console.Write("Hello, {0}, you have {1} messages in your inbox", name, messages);
```

And the compiler will rewrite it for you so that all your different arguments after the first are scooped up and put into an array:

```
Console.Write("Hello, {0}, you have {1} messages in your inbox", new []{name, messages});
```

When the message is being formatted, the array item 0 is put into `{0}`. This means the  `name` will be inserted into `{0}`, the `messages` will be inserted into the `{1}`

Hopefully you can now see why your attempt doesn't print the var; you didn't put a placeholder into the format string it indicate where the var should be printed. I know why you did this; you didn't know you had to because you wouldn't in python etc..

In essence you provided one data item, but put no placeholders. It is permitted to supply more data items than placeholders; extra data items are not used but you cannot supply more placeholders than data items:

```
//this will crash
Console.Write("Hello, {0}, you have {1} messages in your inbox", name);

//but this is fine, it just doesn't have a {1} placeholder so name will appear in the output, but messages will not 
Console.Write("Hello, {0}", name, messages);
```

---

The placeholders can accept formats too, after a colon

```
Console.Write("The temperature is {0:0.00} Celsius  ", temperature);
```

Note: Temperature needs to be some kind of "with decimal points" number, not a string, for a format like 0.00 to work (eg `float temperature = 34.9;`

Don't forget, if you want these things on different lines, you have the WriteLine method

Have a read of the [string.Format documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0#insert-a-string) for a detailed look at string formatting. This version of Write accepts strings on the same pattern as string.Format does

Comment: I'd suggest to show him the more common string concatenation in C#, i.e. `"aaa"+name` or `$"aaa{name}"`. Right now, he's thinking that the first syntax doesn't work because he had put in `Write("kjkkjkj", +name)`. At least that's what it looks like on the error message.

Comment: @Konrad no, because that wouldn't answer the question asked. The question is "why doesn't this work?" followed by an attempt to use C# in the same way as python or JavaScript, ie `print("hi ", name, "you have ", messages, " messages)`.. in those languages it would also add a newline, whereas Write won't, so it's wrong for two reasons.  I've actually answered the question as to why it didn't work in c#; everyone else has *not* answered this question, they've effectively said "you can do it like this" and posted some suggestion which is actually *nothing at all to do with the question*

Comment: @Konrad *Right now, he's thinking that the first syntax doesn't work because he had put in Write("kjkkjkj", +name). At least that's what it looks like on the error message* - that's not the case. There is no error message in the question; the question code compiles and produces unexpected output, not an error message. There is an error message mentioned under another, incorrect, answer; that answer has *caused* that error because the OP did not correctly implement b the advice of the other answer. It's absolutely unjustified to criticize my answer for errors caused by someone else's advice

Comment: Better to explain why it didn't work the way it was expected than to just give a "do this instead" answer. I'd go a step further and give both when applicable. It's entirely necessary to explain that doing one thing in one language and not adjusting for another language will usually be wrong.

Comment: @CaiusJard There's an error message in one of the (now removed) comments. it states something sounding like using plus sign as unary operator, which made me realize that OP did this: `Write("blahablaha", +name)`. My assumption was that he was so entirely convinced that there's no single-parameter version when concating strings that he kept the comma (or simply missed it was still there).

Comment: @CaiusJard Also, just to be very clear - it wasn't my intention to criticize your answer in any way. If it came off as such (which it may, since you mentioned that), I want to apologize. Please excuse my formulation if it was perceived as offensive or harsh. I can't see it myself but our measures may vary, so of respect to your effort, I'm explaining myself.

Comment: I understand; I can't see any indication in the question  that a syntax error like that had been initially performed - I think that the `+name` problem came along as a result of the OP reading Örvar's advice to do `Write("hi " + name);` and the `+` had been added but the comma hadnt been removed, and that all this was done after the question was posted. I'm focused on answering the original question asked, rather than resolving the syntax error caused by a subsequent update, because the reason why the original attempt didn't work is quite different to a syntax error introduced by `+`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
Console.Write("Hello, " + name);
Console.Write("You have " + messages);
```

Or

```
Console.Write($"Hello, {name}");
Console.Write($"You have {messages}");
```

Comment: I tried putting + before the var name: +name and like you did: + name. It just gives me an error, sorry if it's a very basic question, I'm kinda used to python print system lol

Comment: @zDITC5 You must have had wrong syntax, mate. The answer here is correct. And most natural to a C# developer, although there may be other options like `Write($"jshdjsd {name}sdsds")`

Comment: (9,26): error CS0023: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'
(10,28): error CS0023: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'
(15,38): error CS0023: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'

Comment: @zDITC5 You have wrong syntax. I'm guessing you have the comma **outside** the parethenses. Paste in what Örvar shows you and it will work. Promise.

Comment: The second input method works, thanks a lot mate, eventough I'm gonna look up what { } are for there. Thanks again, great day.

Comment: @zDITC5 You're missing my point, mate. **Both** input methods work. And whenyou code C#, the first one is more natural. You're using your Python experience to code C#. I'd advise against it. My suggestion is that you check where you've made the mistake (probably, using the comma to pass a second parameter) and it will work better then.

Comment: I'm gonna take a look at it, the original code is the one showed above, in the first posts, I really can't see the mistake in there, the line: Console.Write("Hello, ", name);
Is well written for what I can see, I know the first one is more natural, since is the one used in Python too. 

Again thanks and I'm gonna take a look at it, see where the mistake is, if there's one.

Comment: @zDITC5 It is not. You need to take a careful look. He doesn't pass a second parameter (as is done in Python).

Comment: @Konrad *You must have had wrong syntax, mate. The answer here is correct* - no, this answer is not correct because it doesn't answer the question. The c# syntax zDITC5 used absolutely **is** a legal c# syntax, because it wouldn't compile if it wasn't, but *it is not being used in the right way*. I think you're perhaps not appreciating/forgetting that there is an overload of Write that works like string.Format, it is this overload that is *incorrectly* being used in a Python way; it doesn't work like that

Comment: @CaiusJard First of all - you are right. So part of me cheers for you there. The other part, is rather prone to see the (possibly incorrectly assumed) need of the OP. The assumptions is that coming form Python's syntax, OP isn't trying to set formatting but concatenate strings. And in such case, explaining (very correctly) the overloaded method will be as useful as braille on the shotgun. I repeat that I'm not arguing against your statement. It just seems like asking *where am I* and getting *in your car*. It's correct. But to the confused asker, perhaps not helping.   :)

Comment: @Konrad *braille on the shotgun* - hah, never heard this one, and I love it. Ultimately I suppose the OP has the best of all worlds; they have an in depth explanation of why their attempt didn't why/why it differs from Python/JS etc, they have advice on how to make it work in that way, and they also have alternatives from other answers of different ways of achieving the same thing, so quite a rounded education. Kudos to all

Answer (score -1):

Try that:

```
// Variables 

        var name = "Bob ";
        var messages = "3 ";
        var temperature = "34,4 ";

        // Print First Part

        Console.Write("Hello, {0}", name);
        Console.Write("You have {0}", messages);
        Console.Write("in your inbox. ");

        //Print Part II

        Console.Write("The temperature is {0}", temperature);
        Console.Write("celsius.");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;

 public class Program
 {
   public static void Main()
    {

     var name = "Bob ";
     var messages = "3 ";
     var temperature = "34,4 ";

    // Print First Part

    Console.Write("Hello, {0}", name);
    Console.Write("You have {0}", messages);
    Console.Write("in your inbox. ");

    //Print Part II

     Console.Write("The temperature is {0}", temperature);
      Console.Write("celsius.");

     Console.ReadKey();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why do you think that `Console.ReadKey();` would answer the OP's question somehow ?

Comment: Console.Readkey() is used to hold the console page of the application